# RecyclerView to EdiTtext

Tags: java, android

I'm using recycleview in google cloud speech api.
And I would like to put the strings in the recycleview into a single edit text.
How do I move a string from a recycleview into a single text?

```
enter code here
/*
* Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
* http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

package com.google.cloud.android.speech;

 import android.Manifest;
 import android.content.ComponentName;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.ServiceConnection;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.icu.util.ValueIterator;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.IBinder;
 import android.sax.Element;
 import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
 import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
 import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.text.TextUtils;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 MessageDialogFragment.Listener {
  static EditText edit1;
 static EditText edit2;
  static EditText edit3;
 static String a1,a2;
  static String[] b1,b2;
  static int count=0;
  Button btn;

  private static final String FRAGMENT_MESSAGE_DIALOG = "message_dialog";

  private static final String STATE_RESULTS = "results";

  private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 1;

  private SpeechService mSpeechService;

  private VoiceRecorder mVoiceRecorder;
  private final VoiceRecorder.Callback mVoiceCallback = new 
  VoiceRecorder.Callback() {

     @Override
     public void onVoiceStart() {
         showStatus(true);
         if (mSpeechService != null) {
            mSpeechService.startRecognizing(mVoiceRecorder.getSampleRate());
         }
     }

    @Override
    public void onVoice(byte[] data, int size) {
        if (mSpeechService != null) {
            mSpeechService.recognize(data, size);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onVoiceEnd() {
        showStatus(false);
        if (mSpeechService != null) {
            mSpeechService.finishRecognizing();
        }
    }

   };

   // Resource caches
   private int mColorHearing;
   private int mColorNotHearing;

   // View references
   private TextView mStatus;
   private TextView mText;
   private ResultAdapter mAdapter;
   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


  private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new 
   ServiceConnection() 
   {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder 
     binder) {
         mSpeechService = SpeechService.from(binder);
         mSpeechService.addListener(mSpeechServiceListener);
         mStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

      @Override
      public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
         mSpeechService = null;
      }

      };

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      edit1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
      edit2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
      edit3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit3);
      btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      final Resources resources = getResources();
      final Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
      mColorHearing = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, 
      R.color.status_hearing, theme);
      mColorNotHearing = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, 
       R.color.status_not_hearing, theme);

      setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
     mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
      mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

      mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
      mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      final ArrayList<String> results = savedInstanceState == null ? null :
            savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(STATE_RESULTS);
      mAdapter = new ResultAdapter(results);
      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



         }
       });

       }

   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();

      // Prepare Cloud Speech API
      bindService(new Intent(this, SpeechService.class), mServiceConnection, 
     BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    // Start listening to voices
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
     Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        startVoiceRecorder();
     } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        showPermissionMessageDialog();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
       {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
     }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
    // Stop listening to voice
    stopVoiceRecorder();

    // Stop Cloud Speech API
    mSpeechService.removeListener(mSpeechServiceListener);
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mSpeechService = null;

    super.onStop();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      if (mAdapter != null) {
          outState.putStringArrayList(STATE_RESULTS, mAdapter.getResults());
      }
     }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
     permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION) {
        if (permissions.length == 1 && grantResults.length == 1
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startVoiceRecorder();
        } else {
            showPermissionMessageDialog();
        }
      } else {
          super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
       grantResults);
       }
    }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_file:

     mSpeechService.recognizeInputStream
      (getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.audio));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
   }

    private void startVoiceRecorder() {
      if (mVoiceRecorder != null) {
          mVoiceRecorder.stop();
     }
      mVoiceRecorder = new VoiceRecorder(mVoiceCallback);
      mVoiceRecorder.start();
     }

    private void stopVoiceRecorder() {
       if (mVoiceRecorder != null) {
        mVoiceRecorder.stop();
        mVoiceRecorder = null;
      }
     }

    private void showPermissionMessageDialog() {
      MessageDialogFragment
            .newInstance(getString(R.string.permission_message))
            .show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_MESSAGE_DIALOG);
      }

    private void showStatus(final boolean hearingVoice) {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            mStatus.setTextColor(hearingVoice ? mColorHearing : 
         mColorNotHearing);
          }
         });
       }

      @Override
   public void onMessageDialogDismissed() {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
      {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
             REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
        }

     private final SpeechService.Listener mSpeechServiceListener =
          new SpeechService.Listener() {
            @Override
             public void onSpeechRecognized(final String text, final boolean 
        isFinal) {
                if (isFinal) {
                    mVoiceRecorder.dismiss();
                }
                if (mText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (isFinal) {
                                mText.setText(null);
                                mAdapter.addResult(text);
                                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);





                            } else {
                                mText.setText(text);


                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

     private static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      TextView text;

      ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_result, parent, false));
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
      }

      }

    private static class ResultAdapter extends 
     RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {   


    private final ArrayList<String> mResults = new ArrayList<>();


     ResultAdapter(ArrayList<String> results) {
        if (results != null) {
            mResults.addAll(results);

          }
      }



      @Override
      public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
          return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), 
      parent);
      }

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.text.setText(mResults.get(position));

      }

     @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
         return mResults.size();
      }

      void addResult(String result) {
          mResults.add(0, result);
         notifyItemInserted(0);
     }

      public ArrayList<String> getResults() {

         return mResults;
       }



      }

    }
```

here is java code.
if you know the answer, let me know..
I tried but it doesn't work. The editview doesn't show all of texts in reclycleview...

Comment: Post the code what you have tried, so that it will be easy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TextView element outside of that recycle view. Then initialize it onCreate() method.

You need to extract text from that recycle view. I have no idea about that u hold data. Anyhow get a text from that.
Then updateText using textView.setText(...) when that recycleText updated

Define TextView like this in mainActivity and initalize it in onCreate

```
static TextView recyText;
```

in

```
oncreate(){
   ....
   recyText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.recyText);

}
```

the update it in below code segment

```
 @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.text.setText(mResults.get(position));
         recyText.setText(recyText.getText()+ " " +mResults.get(position))

      }
```

Comment: @Lia what u mean by "static TextView text1" is it the text view which hold text in recycle view

Comment: I made static TextView text1;   and I added in oncreate  text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);  Also i added setText1(); in new SpeechService.Listener(){  public void run() { if (isFinal)... mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);...(here). And i added public void setText1(){
       a1= mAdapter.getResults().toString().replaceAll("\\s","");
       text1.setText(a1);
    }       Did i do it wrong...? it doesn't work

Comment: I updated it in below code segment you gave to me. But there is a error(non-static field 'recyText' cannot be referenced from a static context. And I have one more question.. how can i  initalize it in onCreate? (Thank you for answering me)

Comment: I updated code again. you need to put static for that TextView. then use i updated code to initalize it in onCreate() method. You need to add text view for your layout as well @Lia

Comment: I did that you told me. When I told hello/ my name/  is Lia ----> I want to see in the textview hello my name is Lia . but  in the textview --> They come out one at a time. hello   /  my name   / is Lia

Comment: @Lia i updated my answer again by adding recyText.setText(recyText.getText()+ " " +mResults.get(position)) . try this as well